# How to implement the red-black ordering for any linear equation system?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to solve linear equations systems using iterative methods, the method that i'm using is Gauss-Seidel, but i'm trying to parallelize the algorithm. I've found a method called red-black ordering but the texts that i've found they discretize some partial differential equations before using the red-black ordering . However what i'm trying to achieve is to use that technique to solve any linear system if it's possible, form example: A = [3 2 -1; 2 -2 4; -1 1/2 -1], x = [x1 x2 x3], b = [1 -2 0]